# Web service API

Tags: web-services, api

Would I be right in thinking that a Web service's API is a client of the Web service, which provides function names to access the Web service?

Comment: Web Service's API will give all details about Service and NOT about client..

Comment: Here is not a good place to share your idea about something general

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, although the last part of your statement may be correct..ish.

API stands for "Application Programmer Interface" (or something along those lines anyway). Basically, an API is a set of specifications, telling a *using party* (the client) how to access some resource (the Web Service).

A client can for instance be an application which connects to a service in accordance with the specifications in an API. This is a general principle (not only for web services), and can be really simple, like for instance the following:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=catnip
```

This is a search query to google. An API states that the value of the parameter `q` (passsed in the url using `?q=<some value>`, should be searched for.

A client could be your web-browser, or any other application which passes that query to Google, and receives the answer it provides.

*Sidenote: The same API also states that there can be more data in the url, such as format, client-information, etc:* `https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=catnip&ie=utf-8`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Let's say you have a Web service and u want to develop an API for the service for clients to use the service. Would the API  be a client firstly?

Comment: Nope. The "API" is not really a "thing", represented in code. It is just a set of abstract rules, which the client must follow in order to use the service. If you write a README-document explaining how your WS works, and how a client can use it, then that can be your API. It tells your users how they can create a client that can use your WS.

Comment: Ok, so SOAP and WDSL or REST and WADL can be the implementation of the API?

Comment: Um.. Kind of. You should probably read about each of these technologies on Wikipedia, for instance. These are just different ways (technologies) to communicate between server and client. The specifics is what you specify in your API. i.e. which messages you've made your service able to accept using any (or each) of these technologies.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time and answers. I'm currently reading REST full Web services, on chapter 2. If I don't fully understand anything in the book, I post a question on here. Im currently preparing for a college project on what goes on behind Web service API s. Any books u recommend?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. As for books... not that I can think of, no. I think just skimming some of the info on Wikipedia should be enough to understand the basics concepts here. Just remember that an "API for X" strictly speaking, just means "instructions for using X". I'm guessing your confusion stems from people using "API" to mean "All the stuff that X provides", which may be sort of unclear... (hope that makes sense?). Good luck with it anyway! :)